# Ruby on Rails showing correct amount of options_for_select in select_tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, iteration, html-select

I think my problem is really small, but I didn't found a good solution in the internet.

```
<%= form_tag url_for(controller: 'courses', action: 'add_teacher') , method: 'put' do%>
<%= select_tag :teacher, options_for_select(Teacher.all.collect {|t| ([t._name, t.id] unless @course.teachers.include?(t))})%>
<%= hidden_field_tag(:course, value = @course.id) %>
<%= submit_tag 'hinzufügen' %>
```

I got this code in my courses/new View. I would like to add one or more teachers for one course, but i don't want to be able to add them twice or more. So I used this:

```
unless @course.teachers.include?(t)
```

The problem is, it still looks like this:[empty rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZBenD.png)

May anyone got a better solution for this problem? what happens if teachers = nil?

thank u for help

Comment: How many teachers do you intend to have on this app? An autocomplete field might be a better solution in the long run.

Comment: @ThomasR.Koll Oh i would love to have a autocomplete field in my search functions. And maybe in this case as well. But I thought it will be too difficult. May u help me with it? :)

Comment: You need an `autocomplete` method on the controller and on the frontend there's plenty of javascript libraries for the job.

Answer (score 1):

You did collection a few `nil` values which you can get rid of with the `compact` at the end.

```
<%= select_tag :teacher, options_for_select(Teacher.all.collect {|t| ([t._name, t.id] unless @course.teachers.include?(t))}.compact )%>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use compact to remove nil values.

```
<%= select_tag :teacher, options_for_select(Teacher.all.collect {|t| ([t._name, t.id] unless @course.teachers.include?(t))}.compact )%>
```

or you can use the below method that will remove " " or nil values

```
<%= select_tag :teacher, options_for_select(Teacher.all.collect {|t| ([t._name, t.id] unless @course.teachers.include?(t))}.select(&:presence) )%>
```

Example for select(&:prescence):

```
Teachers = ["mark", "robin", "", "jack", nil, "steve"]

Teachers .select(&:presence)

["mark", "robin", "jack", "steve"]
```

Example for compact:

```
Teachers = ["mark", "robin", "", "jack", nil, "steve"]

Teachers.compact

["mark", "robin","", "jack", "steve"]
```

Comment: `Teacher.all` will be uniq, no need to double the effort.

Comment: @thomas R Koll make sense :)